# How to extract element within a HTML Tag using Xpath in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an HTML tag that looks like this

```
<tr class="js-row  DC is-odd" data-nationality="Indian" data-team-id="3">
        <td class="top-players__freeze js-pos top-players__pos DC">2</td>
        <td class="top-players__freeze top-players__player">
            <div class="top-players__image">
                <img class="js-headshot" src="//static.iplt20.com/players/210/Photo-Missing.png"
```

I'm trying to extract the data-nationality value using XPath, however I'm not quite sure how to do this.

I have tried something like this, after selecting the tr element:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'js-row  DC is-odd')]/@data-nationality")
```

However this didn't work. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `get_attribute()` element method.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'js-row  DC is-odd')]").get_attribute("data-nationality")
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_attribute-element-method-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close enough. Presuming the value **DC** within `class` and `data-team-id="3"` being two unique attribute values within the element, to print the value of the *data-nationality* attribute i.e. **Indian** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.js-row.DC.is-odd[data-team-id='3']"))).get_attribute("data-nationality"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='js-row  DC is-odd' and @data-team-id='3']"))).get_attribute("data-nationality"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Indian
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```